# php enum без абстрактного класса

Tags: php, enum

подскажите пожалуйста, чем плохо сделать так

```
class Enum{
  public static $view = 'view';
  public static $delete = 'delete';
  public static $add = 'add';
}

 $action = Enum::$view;
 echo $action;
```

почему https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum вот здесь используется абстрактный класс?

Comment: Нельзя создать экземпляр абстрактного класса, а вашего - можно(это то что пришло в голову первым), но думаю таких камней еще много, и этот лишь сразу бросился в глаза

Comment: а чем плохо то, что можно создать экземпляр класса?

Comment: А для чего вам создавать экземпляр пустого класса? те кто будут пользоваться вашей "библиотекой" могут не знать что этот класс "абстрактен" и используется как группа констант, и создавать его экземпляры =) собсно делать его абстрактным это не обязательное требование, которое улучшает читаемость и понимание кода, а так же позволяет избежать некоторых ошибок в будующем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всегда лучше работать с объектами чем со строками(как в вашем случае).

Вот почему:

---

Доступны все возможности ООП - [инкапсуляция, наследование, полиморфизм](http://www.php.su/php/intro/?11), а в случае использования класса с публичными статическими свойствами - нет.

---

При передаче в коде, вы гарантируете, что это именно нужный экземпляр, а не просто строка:

```
public function getContent(ViewEnum $enum)
```

VS

```
public function getContent(string $enum)
```

---

Используя [это решение](https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum) вы получаете дополнительную функциональность, например isValid метод который помогает проверить корректность значения. Вы можете унаследоваться и добавить свою функциональность.

---

Вот примеры нескольких задач для сравнения:

---

**Получить массив всех значений списка:**

В вашем случае:

```
$result = [Enum::$view, Enum::$view, Enum::$view];
```

В случае php-enum:

```
$result = Enum::toArray();
```

---

**Проверить, что пришло корректное значение:**

В вашем случае

```
in_array($value, [Enum::$view, Enum::$delete, Enum::$add]);
```

В случае php-enum:

```
$result = Enum::isValid($value);
```

---

**Проверить, что полученное значение, равняется delete**

В вашем случае:

```
$value === Enum::$delete
```

В случае php-enum:

```
$value->equals(Enum::DELETE())
```

или

```
$value->isDelete()
```

если добавить соответствующий метод.