# Зачем нужен Enum в php?

Tags: php, enum

Подскажите зачем нужны пакеты [clabs/php-enum](https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum), [spatie/enum](https://github.com/spatie/enum) или [dbalabka/php-enumeration](https://github.com/dbalabka/php-enumeration)? В каких случаях их применять?

Comment: Они нужны для использования в виде списка как аналог [перечисляемых типов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF), которых нет в PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для возможности работать с константам как с объектами, используется большынстве в ValueObject, к примеру:

Банальный пример - у нас єсть класс **User** со статусом.

```
class User
{
    private const ACTIVE  = 'active';
    private const WAIT    = 'wait';
    private const DELETE  = 'delete';
    private const ARCHIVE = 'archive';

    privat string $status;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->status = self::WAIT;
    }

    public function isActive(): bool
    {
         return $this->status === self::ACTIVE;
    }

    public function isWait(): bool
    {
         return $this->status === self::WAIT;
    }

    public function isDelete(): bool
    {
         return $this->status === self::DELETE;
    }

    public function isArchive(): bool
    {
         return $this->status === self::ARCHIVE;
    }

    public function activate(): void
    {
        $this->status = self::ACTIVE;
    }
}

$user = new User();

if (true === $user->isWait()) {
    $user->activate();
}
```

Наш клас разрастается и что не очень хорошо, если можно некоторые компоненты вынести в маленькие детали его сущности.
С помощью библиотеки мы можем заделать со статуса EnumType и разгрузить клас User:

```
class User
{

    private Status $status;


    public function __construct(): bool
    {
        $this->status = Status::WAIT();
    }

    public function activate(): void
    {
        $this->status = Status::ACTIVE();
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

}


class Status extends Enum 
{
    public const ACTIVE  = 'active';
    public const WAIT    = 'wait';
    public const DELETE  = 'delete';
    public const ARCHIVE = 'archive';    

    public function isActive(): bool
    {
         retutn $this->is(self::ACTIVE);
    }

    public function isWait(): bool
    {
         retutn $this->is(self::WAIT);
    }

    public function isDelete(): bool
    {
         retutn $this->is(self::DELETE);
    }

    public function isArchive(): bool
    {
         retutn $this->is(self::ARCHIVE);
    }
}

$user = new User();

if (true === $user->getStatus()->isWait()) {
    $user->activate();
}
```

И откуда уже можно и получать списки всех констант для проверки и тд.
Я собственно использую єту [библиотеку](https://github.com/marc-mabe/php-enum) но в связке с датамапером, к примеру как [вод тут](https://github.com/mistery23/laravel-value-objects), в зависимости какой фреймвор, и что он может предложить.
Суть в общем в том, чтобы работать с константным значениям как с объектом.
Надеюсь я ответил на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я не понимаю профита от этой обёртки?

Comment: Вы не обязаны использовать именно эту обвёртку, если использовать самописцы вы могли бы сами написать методы, которые дает даная библиотека к примеру как вот хранения локали в symfony  https://i.imgur.com/o01Bk4s.png , библиотека просто использует магию при вызове несуществующего статического метода и вам ненужно будет писать методы по питу Status::wait() і тд, просто оглашаете константы, а обвёртка уже все сделает самостоятельно.

Comment: Я немного не это имел в виду. Я имел в виду, какой профит от того, что я напишу `User::wait()` от `User::WAIT`?

Comment: Наводил же пример выше, чтобы вынести код (сделать клас User тоньше) и работать не со скалярным значениям, а с объектом, так как туда можно вынести проверки и тд. Когда у вас у юзера будет 6 статусов, 8 локален, 4 роли константами, и з множеством проверок к кним, клас уже бутит нереально большой, а там ещё будет суто своих методов хватать, по типу - атача сот сети, сброса пароля, смены мыла і тд., а так вы вынесете константы в отдельные запчасти юзера, со своими методами, и в случае чего вам не нужно будет искать где же у вас метод проверти статуса или его роли.

Comment: У вас будет маленькая самодостаточная Enum запчасть, а обвёртка избавит вас от написания методов которых я предоставил на скриншотє выше. Ещё раз повторю суть работать не со скалярным значениям, а с объектом, так как объект более гибки.

Comment: @doox911 вот примеры профитов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1072503/php-enum-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0 

Один из основных защита "от дурака" - нельзя будет засетить невалидное значение.  $user->setStatus(User::WAIT) - кто помешает туда засетить что-то левое? Только если ставить в сететр проверку. И так каждый раз, что неудобно.

Comment: @Pavel, у меня в голове не укладываются две вещи: 1. Почему эти классы называют `Enumerable`(перечисляемый)? 2. Насколько я понял, а понимаю я пока слабо, я могу написать класс `Status` и описать эти методы без магии либ. Не используя например, `new class()`. И так же наследовать его в `User`.

Comment: @doox911 пользователь будет наследовать класс где статусы? Это же логиечская дичь. А если будет несколько полей, трейты?  Это если класс собаки будет наследовать класс нога. Тут должна быть или агрегация (в случае с статусами) или композиция (в случае с ногой). 
Класс называется перечисляемый, потому что имеет всего неколько возможных значений, и никаких больше. Просто нельзя другие выставить "Защита от дурака". Т.е. если использовать просто строки, кто-то может ошибиться и выставить невалидную строку. Даже мимо сеттера. с Таким классом это неполучится. Особенно с введением типизации.

Comment: @doox911 написать класс мжно и самому, но зачем если есть готовые проверенные библиотки.П.С. я сам не понимал смысл енама, пока не показали этот пример и примеры по ссылке выше, которую я скинул. Спасибо за вопрос))